# Presenting an portrait view from phone on an rotated landscape monitor

Tags: ios, iphone, sprite-kit, device-orientation

I have a big problem with device orientations and hope you can help me.

I have to write an iOS App which is fully made for portrait mode. This app has to be presented on an 90 degree rotated TV. The problem is, I can't tell the monitor, that he is rotated and so he shows the input-source normal, which is the screen from the iOS-Device with large black borders on the right and left (or now, after rotation, at top and bottom).

My question is: Is there a way to tell the monitor, that he gets an landscape view.
Or is there an easy way to write an portrait app for landscape mode, so that it completely feels like portrait? (I thought about using Sprite Kit - the App has not so much view content - is that an alternative?)

Thank you for every hint!

Answer (score 0):

you can try to set-up landscape orientation (right angle of rotation) at System Preferences -> Displays.

1) System Preferences
[image]

2) Screen Rotation
[image]

Comment: Can you specify this, please?

Comment: I added few shots to answer to help you

Comment: ah thank you - the problem is, the monitor is not paired with a Mac OS X device, only with an iOS device.

Comment: Please, explain your last comment: what type of device paired with what?

Comment: I will pair an iOS Device (e.g. iPad Mini) with an LG TV (without an settings-option for portrait mode).